# Is a non-compact Riemannian manifold a "measure space"?

Tags: functional-analysis, manifolds, lp-spaces

One can define $L^p$ spaces for measure spaces with a given measure. Is a non-compact (i.e., it has a boundary) bounded Riemannian manifold a measure space? I am thinking of the manifold $(0,T) \times S$ where $S$ is a $n-1$ dimensional hypersurface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to know so I can use the $L^p$ theory already available. Are there any technicalities I need to worry about?  Basically I want density of continuous functions on a manifold that I have in mind. Thanks.

Comment: If your manifold has boundary, just remove it. Every Riemannian manifold has a volume form.  A volume form defines a measure. Of course, the total measure of your manifold can be infinite, but this is not a problem, just think about the definition of $L^p({\mathbb R})$.

Comment: @studiosus pseudo-form if not orientable. /nitpicking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As studiosus explained, the canonical measure is available, given by the [volume (pseudo-)form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form#Relation_to_measures).

To show that continuous (or smooth) functions are dense in $L^p(M)$, use a partition of unity into compactly supported functions, each of which is supported in a coordinate patch (an open set diffeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb R^n$). This makes it possible to transfer the density result from $\mathbb R^n$ to the manifold.